# React ref for a react element passed as a prop, dynamic event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm building a dropdown component which gets a button element as a prop.
This is a short description of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
   render() {
     let button = this.props.trigger;
     // How do I get a ref to the button native DOM node?
     // How can I attach a react event to the button?

   }
}
```

And this is how I want to use it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
          <Dropdown trigger={<button>Click me</button>}>
               dropdown content
          </Dropdown>
    )
   }
}
```

In short, If I have a variable with a react element,
1. How can I get a ref to the button dom node passed as a prop? (I need to pass it to `dom-align`).
2. How can I attach event listeners to the passed button element?

Answer (score 0):

That is how you can do it with an arrow function component for the button and pass ref and event listeners.

```
const Button = ({buttonRef, onEvent}) => <button ref={buttonRef} onEvent />

class Parent extends Component {
  methodForButton = e => {...}
  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        propButton={
         <Button buttonRef={el => this.buttonElement = el} onEvent={this.methodForButton} />
        }
      >{...}<Dropdown />
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can pass the Button as a children not a prop

```
<Dropdown><Button /><Dropdown />
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use the dropdown children for the dropdown content. The dropdown will be positioned bellow the button. Can you please explain why you use a Button component (and not just regular element). I'm not sure I understand what you did

Comment: It's the react way to do it, arrow function to render dom with a button. you can use the first part. that exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
//For creating reference const (inside constructor)
  ref_name = React.createRef();
// For connect ref to html
   <tag ref={this.ref_name}></tag>

// For creating event create a class method
   handleClick(){}
//Register it inside constructor
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
// attach with html
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.button_ref = React.createRef();
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }
   handleClick(event){
       //write your code...
   }

   render() {
       return (
                <Dropdown trigger={<button ref={this.button_ref} onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>}>
                   dropdown content
                </Dropdown>
       )
   }
}
```